# Off-the-shelf function to search for key of given value in a Python dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to find all keys of a dictionary that are mapped to a given value (similar to what `np.where` would do for arrays). For instance :

```
dict = {'a':12, 'b':0, 'c':0}
print(where(dict, 0))
>>> ['b', 'c']
```

Obviously, I can do it with :

```
[key for key in dict.keys() if dict[key]==0]
```

but I would like to know if there is already a Python function that performs this operation.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There's no builtin function for that. Another way is to use `filter`.

Comment: Or `[key for key, value in dict.items() if value == 0]`

Comment: If there was, it would likely have the same *order* as your code, as no value to key(s) mapping is present in a map / dictionary. That fact alone would make me stop looking for it if it cannot be immediately found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no python built in function for performing it. 
You can use `filter`:

```
my_dict = {
    'a': 12, 
    'b': 0,
    'c': 0
}
print(list(filter(lambda x: my_dict[x] == 0, my_dict)))
```

You can use also numpy:

```
keys = np.array(list(my_dict.keys()))
values = np.array(list(my_dict.values()))
print(keys[values == 0])
```